# How do i get all <a> tags from my <ul> which is my parent node

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to select all the `<a>` tags from my a parent tag of `<ul>`. I tried `$("ul").children().children();` but is there a better way

```html
<ul class="chat-inbox" id="chat-inbox">
  <li><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."></li>
  <!-- ko foreach: messageModels() -->
  <li>
    <a data-bind="click:$parent.startChat.bind()" style="cursor: pointer" href="#">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object img-circle" src="assets/images/ici-avatar.jpg">
          <span class="badge badge-red" data-bind="text:unreadMessagesCount()">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <p class="media-heading"><span data-bind="text:friend.userName()">Ing. Imrich Kamarel</span> <span class="time" data-bind="text: $parent.convertTime(messages()[messages().length - 1].dateCreated())">12:44</span></p>
          <span class="message" data-bind="text:messages()[messages().length - 1].message()">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.</span>
          <div class="chat-actions">
            <span class="mark-unread" title="Mark as unread"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></span>
            <span class="archive" title="Archive"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: `$("ul a")` in the most general way … lots of other ways to be more specific if necessary.

Comment: `$('ul li').children('a')` or `$('ul > li > a')` if you only want the top-level `a` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul#chat-inbox li > a');
//also worked 
$('ul#chat-inbox li  a');
```

Some li and a i have added for testing Try the above code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Support

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to do with your code and if you're going to be chaining events or not.

If you just want to select all `<a>` elements within a `<ul>` then the quickest and most general option is:

```
$('ul a');
```

However, if you want to chain events, such as:

```
$(..).addClass('..');
```

Then you're best to use jQuery .find and target elements by ID. For example, based on your code the best option for performance would be:

```
$('#chat-inbox').find('a').addClass('test');
```